# Можно ли удалить огромное количество файлов в директoрии?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

Есть ли консольное решение следующей проблемы? В папка имеется очень-очень много файлов типа:

```
xaaaacqjz
xaaaacqka
xaaaacqkb
xaaaacqkc
xaaaacqkd
xaaaacqke
xaaaacqkf
xaaaacqkg
```

Их там настолько много, что thunar просто перестает отвечать, в общем в гуйне не могу решить проблему.

Можно как-то их удалить командой rm? Можно было бы кочнено полностью выпилить папку, но там у меня слишком много годного материала. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: `$ find /путь/к/каталогу -maxdepth 1 -type f -name xaaaa\* -delete`

Comment: Уверен, что это бы помогло) Но к сожалению, я сделал почти так же, но немножк не так, и ничего не осталось) Осталась лишь системка, как с нуля!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ответы - в ответы?

Comment: @misdeed, обычно удалённые файлы можно восстановить? По крайней мере, на ntfs можно, про линуксовые файловые системы не в курсе...

Comment: @Qwertiy, да зачем их восстанавливать? Удалились, и пусть) Новых закачаю...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

вообще, конечно, удалить файлы можно программой *rm*:

```
$ rm список файлов
```

в частности, к примеру, файлов в каталоге `/путь/к/каталогу`, подпадающих под маску `xaaaa*`:

```
$ rm /путь/к/каталогу/xaaaa*
```

но если файлов так много, что полный их список не укладывается в ограничение на длину списка аргументов (`$ getconf ARG_MAX` покажет это ограничение — в байтах), то (ещё в процессе формирования списка аргументов) вы получите ошибку:

> bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long

в таком случае можно воспользоваться программой *find*:

```
$ find /путь/к/каталогу -maxdepth 1 -type f -name xaaaa\* -delete
```