# Удалить все файлы указанные в списке

Tags: linux, bash

Есть файл в котором записаны пути к файлам (много тысяч строк). Каждый путь на новой строке, вроде того:

```
files/1/5a9d25d4b9b50/5a9d2888e329b.jpg
files/2/5a9d25d5444aa/5a9d288984a73.jpg
files/1/5a9d25d4b9b50/5a9d288a0125b.jpg
files/2/5a9d25d5444aa/5a9d288a97c47.jpg
```

Пути относительные (я запущу скрипт из этой папки). Надо собственно удалить их все. Как это можно на bash сделать? Или проще будет через какой-нибудь питон?

Comment: Кажется нагуглил [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149203/shell-command-script-to-delete-files-whose-names-are-in-a-text-file) `rm -f $(<list.txt)`

Comment: при большом списке будет ошибка. см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/843733/178576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

так как файлов много, то, чтобы избежать ошибки при построении списка файлов, конструкции `for f in $(cat список.файлов)` стоит избегать (см. [мой ответ на схожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/843733/178576)). лучше передать список конвейером и обрабатывать имена по одному:

```
cat список.файлов | while read f ...
```

чтобы экранировать спец-символы (например, пробелы), которые могут встретиться в именах файлов, переменную, содержащую имя файла, стоит заключить в кавычки.

итого:

```
cat список.файлов | while read f; do rm "$f"; done
```

Comment: А чем это решение лучше чем через xargs? С xargs тоже ошибка может быть на большом списке?

Comment: см. второй абзац. будет ошибка при наличии специсимволов (например, пробела) в именах. нет, ошибки при большом списке в случае `команда < файл` не будет.

Comment: Yet another *useless use of cat*.

Answer (score 1):

```
xargs rm -f < file_with_names.txt
```

Comment: при наличии спецсимволов (например, пробелов) в именах будут ошибки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, по условию задачи спецсимволов не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Например скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

for I in `cat ./you.file`
do
    rm -f "${I}"
done
```

Comment: с большим списком будет ошибка

Comment: в чем ошибка будет? Там буфферизированный  ввод/вывод

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/843733/178576 . проверьте.

Comment: Это уже не проблема скрипта, а проблема подготовки списка, `split` команда спасёт от этих проблем :) и это актуально для аргументов команды rm, но в данном случае, на вход подаётся только 2 аргумента, так что не этот случай.

Comment: список может переполниться при выполнении команды *for* — если программа *cat* выдаст строку, превышающую по длине `ARG_MAX`.

Comment: да, кстати, пробелы в именах файлов будут обработаны как разделители лексем, т.е., будут ошибки.